# 'Object is in use elsewhere' error on InitializeComponent and with invoke/lock

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with a textbox where I need to update the textbox from multiple threads. Since I am updating the textbox from multiple threads, I am using the following code to make sure it is being invoked from the main thread if necessary - but even with this code I am still getting errors - specifically "Object is currently in use elsewhere".

The code that I used:

```
private static readonly object setTextLockObject = new object();
delegate void SetTextCallBack(XtraForm Form, string ControlToUpdate, string ControlValue);

public void UpdateControlText(XtraForm Form, string ControlToUpdate, string ControlValue)
{
    try
    {
        if (Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallBack callBackHandler = UpdateControlText;
            IAsyncResult invokeResult = Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].BeginInvoke(callBackHandler, Form, ControlToUpdate, ControlValue);
            Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].EndInvoke(invokeResult);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                lock (setTextLockObject)
                {
                    Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].Text = ControlValue.Translate();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                UpdateStatus(string.Format("ControlText1: {0} ControlToUpdate={1}ControlText={2}", x.Message, ControlToUpdate, ControlValue));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         UpdateStatus(string.Format("ControlText2: {0} ControlToUpdate={1} ControlText={2}", ex.Message, ControlToUpdate, ControlValue));
    }
}
```

I am updating the text with an invoke, and making sure to lock the object so that another thread should not be able to access the onject while being updated. I would expect the second thread to wait for the lock to be released, but instead I am getting the "object is currently in use".  Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

I have an even bigger issue where while doing an applicatin tun on a form - in the `InitializeComponent` I am also getting "Object is currently in use elsewhere". This is a new object, and not being used anywhere else. Why would I possibly get this error while initializing the components?

```
at System.Drawing.Graphics.get_PageUnit()
at DevExpress.Utils.Text.FontsCache.GetFontCacheByFont(Graphics graphics, Font font)
at DevExpress.Utils.Text.FontsCache.GetStringSize(Graphics graphics, String text, Font font, StringFormat stringFormat, Int32 maxWidth)
at DevExpress.Utils.Text.TextUtils.GetStringSize(Graphics g, String text, Font font, StringFormat stringFormat, Int32 maxWidth)
at DevExpress.Utils.Paint.XPaintMixed.CalcTextSize(Graphics g, String s, Font font, StringFormat strFormat, Int32 maxWidth)
at DevExpress.Utils.AppearanceObject.CalcTextSize(Graphics g, StringFormat sf, String s, Int32 width)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.LabelControlViewInfo.CalcSimpleTextSize(String Text, Boolean useHotkeyPrefix, LabelAutoSizeMode mode, Int32 predWidth)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.LabelControlViewInfo.CalcTextSize(String Text, Boolean useHotkeyPrefix, LabelAutoSizeMode mode, Int32 predWidth)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.SetBounds(Rectangle bounds, BoundsSpecified specified)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.CommonProperties.SetAutoSize(IArrangedElement element, Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_AutoSize(Boolean value)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl.set_AutoSizeMode(LabelAutoSizeMode value)
at AccessControl.frmRefillCard.InitializeComponent()
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the lock by the way - since everything at that point is happening in the single UI thread, you can't get multiple threads accessing the text at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating things by having the `UpdateControlText` method call itself on the UI thread. The `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` also don't make sense as you're calling them in succession.

How about:

```
public void UpdateControlText(XtraForm Form, string ControlToUpdate, string ControlValue)
{
    if (Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].InvokeRequired)
    {
        try
        {
            Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate]
                .Invoke(() => Form.Controls[ControlToUpdate].Text = ControlValue.Translate());
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            UpdateStatus(string.Format("ControlText1: {0} ControlToUpdate={1}ControlText={2}", 
                x.Message, ControlToUpdate, ControlValue));
        }
    }
}
```